# C: Storing Child process id in another array but not working

Tags: c, fork, pid

I am trying to make an array that stores all the Child process id, and then use them later, however it doesn't seem like working.

```
int numChild = 3;
int childPid[numChild+1];
int childPid2[numChild+1]; //stores the ChildPid 
int AllPid[numChild+1];
for(int i=1;i<= numChild; i++){ 
    if(fork() == 0){    
        childPid[i] = getpid();
        printf("Child %d pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",i,childPid[i],getppid());
        childPid2[i] = childPid[i];
        exit(0);
    } else{
        AllPid[i] = getpid();
    }
}
for (int i=0; i < numChild; i++){
    wait(NULL);
} 
for(int i=1;i<= numChild; i++){ //
    printf("Child %d pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",i,childPid2[i],getppid());
}
```

The result is:

```
Child 1 pid 37917 from [parent] pid 37916
Child 2 pid 37918 from [parent] pid 37916
Child 3 pid 37919 from [parent] pid 37916
Child 1 pid 0 from [parent] pid 21171
Child 2 pid -3 from [parent] pid 21171
Child 3 pid 0 from [parent] pid 21171
```

Maybe I'm not understanding this concept well, but I don't understand why the pid (37917, 37918, 37919) can't  be stored in the array. Thank you.

Comment: You are setting the values in the child process and then trying to print them from the parent process. That can't work as the two processes have seperate address spaces.

Comment: What is the point of setting the current child pid in that array from the child process? You can already get that pid any time you want (and you do so already once... using `getpid`). If anything you should be doing something with the result of `fork` besides throwing it away after assessing it was/was-not zero. If it is non-zero the result will be pid of the child just-created. All the current `AllPid[i] = getpid();` logic does is save the same parent process id in every slot, making it effectively worthless. The one place you can reap child pids in the parent process you're choosing not to.